# Open URL instead of balloon in KML

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I have a country borders for all countries in Europe. When the user clicks on Spain for example the balloon shows up and in there is a table of other links.

I would like to have the user click the country and have it open a new URL in another page instead of showing the balloon. Is this possible in Google Maps?

Comment: Not in Google Maps, but using the Google Maps Javascript API v3

Answer (score 0):

In a file type KML typically the information displayed in infowindow when you click on a polygon is contained in the  and  tag. So if what is written in these tags conforms to the HTML code of a tag  in info windows will show the desired link

This is an example of these tags pleased useful information for a link

```
<name> Water: B0000.S0000.F0724.M00000000 </ name>
<description> ID: 1 & lt; br / & gt; Common Code (Belfiore): 0000 & lt; br / & gt; Section 0000 & lt; br / & gt; Sheet: 0724 & lt; br / & gt; Mappale: 00000000 & lt; br / & gt; & lt; a href = 'http: //www.dfxtrial.altervista.org/catone/fiumicino/B0000.S0000.F0724.M00000000'&gt; Detailed Information ... & lt; / a & gt;   </ description>
```

It 'obvious that to achieve the desired result it is necessary to have a KML file appropriately amended in this sense.
In my case I left the original KML file and or taken steps to integrate them with the information and scripts needed.